# Filtering my R data frame is causing it to sort the data frame incorrectly

Tags: r

Consider the following two code snippets.

A:

```
download.file("https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2FGDP.csv", destfile = "./data/gdp.csv", method = "curl" )
gdp <- read.csv('./data/gdp.csv', header=F, skip=5, nrows=190) # Specify nrows, get correct answer

download.file("https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2FEDSTATS_Country.csv", destfile = "./data/education.csv", method = "curl" )
education = read.csv('./data/education.csv')

mergedData <- merge(gdp, education, by.x='V1', by.y='CountryCode')
# No need to remove unranked countries because we specified nrows
# No need to convert V2 from factor to numeric
sortedMergedData = arrange(mergedData, -V2)
sortedMergedData[13,1] # Get KNA, correct answer
```

B:

```
download.file("https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2FGDP.csv", destfile = "./data/gdp.csv", method = "curl" )
gdp <- read.csv('./data/gdp.csv', header=F, skip=5) # Don't specify nrows, get incorrect answer

download.file("https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2FEDSTATS_Country.csv", destfile = "./data/education.csv", method = "curl" )
education = read.csv('./data/education.csv')

mergedData <- merge(gdp, education, by.x='V1', by.y='CountryCode')
mergedData = mergedData[which(mergedData$V2 != ""),] # Remove unranked countries
mergedData$V2 = as.numeric(mergedData$V2) # make V2 a numeric column
sortedMergedData = arrange(mergedData, -V2)
sortedMergedData[13,1] # Get SRB, incorrect answer
```

I would think the two code snippets would be identical, except that in A you never add the unranked countries to your dataframe and in B you add them but then remove them.  Why is the sorting different for these two code snippets?

The file downloads are from Coursera's Getting and Cleaning Data class (Quiz 3, Question 3).

Edit: To avoid security concerns, I've pasted the raw .csv files below

gdp.csv - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4aRZwBRd

education.csv - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0pbhDCSX

Edit2: The problem is occurring in the `as.numeric` step.  For case B, here is `mergedData$V2` before and after `mergedData$V2 = as.numeric(mergedData$V2)` is applied:

```
> mergedData$V2
  [1] 161 105 60  125 32  26  133 172 12  27  68  162 25  140 128 59  76  93 
 [19] 138 111 69  169 149 96  7   153 113 167 117 165 11  20  36  2   99  98 
 [37] 121 30  182 166 81  67  102 51  4   183 33  72  48  64  38  159 13  103
 [55] 85  43  155 5   185 109 6   114 86  148 175 176 110 42  178 77  160 37 
 [73] 108 71  139 58  16  10  46  22  47  122 40  9   116 92  3   50  87  145
 [91] 120 189 178 15  146 56  136 83  168 171 70  163 84  74  94  82  62  147
[109] 141 132 164 14  188 135 129 137 151 130 118 154 127 152 34  123 144 39 
[127] 126 18  23  107 55  66  44  89  49  41  187 115 24  61  45  97  54  52 
[145] 8   142 19  73  119 35  174 157 100 88  186 150 63  80  21  158 173 65 
[163] 124 156 31  143 91  170 184 101 79  17  190 95  106 53  78  1   75  180
[181] 29  57  177 181 90  28  112 104 134
194 Levels:  .. Not available.   1 10 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 ... Note: Rankings include only those economies with confirmed GDP estimates. Figures in italics are for 2011 or 2010.
> mergedData$V2 = as.numeric(mergedData$V2)
> mergedData$V2
  [1]  72  10 149  32 118 111  41  84  26 112 157  73 110  49  35 147 166 185
 [19]  46  17 158  80  58 188 159  63  19  78  23  76  15 105 122 104 191 190
 [37]  28 116  94  77 172 156   7 139 126  95 119 162 135 153 124  69  37   8
 [55] 176 130  65 137  97  14 148  20 177  57  87  88  16 129  90 167  71 123
 [73]  13 161  47 146  70   4 133 107 134  29 127 181  22 184 115 138 178  54
 [91]  27 101  90  59  55 144  44 174  79  83 160  74 175 164 186 173 151  56
[109]  50  40  75  48 100  43  36  45  61  38  24  64  34  62 120  30  53 125
[127]  33  91 108  12 143 155 131 180 136 128  99  21 109 150 132 189 142 140
[145] 170  51 102 163  25 121  86  67   5 179  98  60 152 171 106  68  85 154
[163]  31  66 117  52 183  82  96   6 169  81 103 187  11 141 168   3 165  92
[181] 114 145  89  93 182 113  18   9  42
```

Can anyone explain why the numbers change when I apply `as.numeric()`?

Comment: It  would be best to show a small sample of the data and apply that to the code, showing where the problems are.  I doubt people are going to be willing to download the data

Comment: Please check if there are factor columns.  As you used a subset in the first case, and without dropping the levels,the ordering might be based on the levels on the factor variable (not tested)

Comment: @RichardScriven, I've added the csv files as pastie links.  I hope that addresses security concerns, or do you think there is another reason people would not download the files?

Comment: @akrun, `gdp$V1` is indeed a factor variable in case B before I convert that column to a numeric.  However, once I convert the column to a numeric, shouldn't it behave as any other numeric?

Comment: @EricBaldwin I looked into both cases. In the second one, for `gdp`, if you look at the `str(gdp)`, except the `V3`, all others are factors. while in the first case,  the factor columns are `V1, V4, and V6.  You have skipped some header lines, likewise, there are some lines in the footer needs to be skipped.  Just check `tail(gdp[,2])`

Comment: @akrun, I understand that in the second case I should get rid of the lines at the end of the file.  However, I should be getting rid of those lines after I merge the data using `mergedData = mergedData[which(mergedData$V2 != ""),]`.  After that line is called, `nrow(mergedData` is 189, the same as in case A after the merge.

Comment: I've updated the original explanation with some additional information; the problem is with `mergedData$V2 = as.numeric(mergedData$V2)`

Comment: @EricBaldwin But, the levels of that factor will still remain if you didn't convert to character

Comment: You're right, @akrun.  If I run `mergedData$V2 = as.character(mergedData$V2); mergedData$V2 = as.numeric(mergedData$V2)` in case B and then continue as normal, I get the correct answer.  Feel free to submit an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real reason for getting different results are in the second case i.e. the full dataset have some footer notes, which were also read with the `read.csv` resulting in most of the columns to be 'factor' class because of the 'character' elements in the footer.  This could have avoided either by

1. skipping the last few lines using `skip` argument in `read.csv`
2. using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the `read.csv` call along with skipping the lines.

The columns were ordered based on the "levels" of the factor.

If you have already read the files without skipping the lines, convert to the respective classes.  If it is 'numeric' column, convert it to numeric by `as.numeric(as.character(df$column))` or `as.numeric(levels(df$column))[df$column]`.